# How to remove "run context configuration" in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to remove Codeception from "run context configuration". Here is what I mean:

[image]

I added Codeception to the project a while ago and I have not used it since then. Thus, I do not need to see it when I want to run a test. Currently I have tests only in PhpUnit and I do not want to choose it every time I run a single test. Ideally, I would like to choose which directory should be associated with PhpUnit and which with Codeception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use Codeception in this project, you can just remove it at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks`, that would do the trick.